# XSLT: Is there a way to "inherit" canned functionality?

Tags: xslt, inheritance, code-reuse, code-templates

i am once again having to cobble together a bit of XSLT into order to turn generated XML into (rather than simply generating HTML).

i'm having huge deja-vu this time again. i'm once again having to solve again basic problems, e.g.:

- how to convert characters into valid html entity references
- how to preserve whitespace/carriage returns when converting to html
- how to convert to HTML as opposed to xhtml
- how to convert dates from **xml format** into presentable format
- how to tear apart strings with substring

This is all stuff that i've solved many times before. But every time i come back to XSLT i have to start from scratch, re-inventing the wheel every time.

If it were a programming language i would have a library of canned functions and procedures i can call. i would have subroutines to perform the commonly repeated tasks. i would inherit from a base class that already implements the ugly boilerplate stuff.

Is there any way in XSLT to grow, expand and improve the ecosystem with canned code?

Comment: Excellent Question (+1). See my answer for extensive, detailed information. :)

Comment: "This is all stuff that i've solved many times before. But every time i come back to XSLT i have to start from scratch, re-inventing the wheel every time" -- This is how I feel with other programming languages as well, if I haven't touched them for quite a while. And yes, XSLT is a bit different than C/Java/Ruby/..., so I think it is quite natural to feel like "start over again". Programming is a rather complex task, and I would be (am) scared of people who go back to a language after a year and don't need to look up anything.

Comment: @Dimitre, calm down. This happens to everybody, no need to get upset. someone downvoted my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669813/how-do-i-prevent-duplicates-in-xsl/2670236#2670236 ), and didn't give a reason. So what? Who cares? Perhaps this person didn't like my nose?

Comment: @Patrick: You are absolutely right! Sometimes I forget that in SO the "law of the big numbers" rules, and the experts should be patient enough... What sometimes upsets me is to see how ignorance and hate win -- one is left only to believe that this is temporary.

Comment: @Dimitre: (This is getting really off-topic, you can "flag" me if you want.) It is so easy to up/downvote anonymously (and SO is very much anonymous), if the people would have to meet in real live before being able to up/downvote, then downvotes would practically not occur, because then we begin to see the person behind the post.

Answer (score 3):

> This is all stuff that i've solved
>   many times before. But every time i
>   come back to XSLT i have to start from
>   scratch, re-inventing the wheel every
>   time.

**This isn't necessary, of course**.

> If it were a programming language

**Yes, XSLT *is* a programming language**.

> i would have a library of canned
>   functions and procedures i can call. i
>   would have subroutines to perform the
>   commonly repeated tasks.

**Yes, you *can* do this in XSLT.**

> i would
>   inherit from a base class that already
>   implements the ugly boilerplate stuff.

**Yes, there *is* something quite similar in XSLT**.

> Is there any way in XSLT to grow,
>   expand and improve the ecosystem with
>   canned code?

**Even in XSLT 1.0 there are powerful, standard features that support reusability**:

1. [**`<xsl:import>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#import)
2. [**`<xsl:include>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#include)
3. [**`<xsl:apply-templates>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Applying-Template-Rules)
4. [**`<xsl:call-template>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#named-templates)
5. [**`<xsl:apply-imports>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#apply-imports)

**XSLT 2.0 adds a few even more powerful features**:

6. [**`<xsl:function>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#stylesheet-functions)
7. [**Parameters for `<xsl:apply-imports>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#apply-imports)
8. [**`<xsl:next-match>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-next-match)

**There have been several XSLT libraries for quite some time**:

1. [**FXSL**](http://fxsl.sf.net) ([**1.x**](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.html) and [**2.x**](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html)) implements Higher-Order Functions in XSLT 1.0/2.0
2. [**FunctX**](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/) -- a library of useful XSLT 2.0 and XQuery functions.

[**XPath 2.1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-21/) and [**XSLT 2.1**](http://xmlguru.cz/2010/03/prague-xslt-wg-f2f) **add Higher-Order Functions as standard**. Functions become first-class datatypes.