# DomDoc/SimpleXML/XSLT: parsing to add auto-incrementing id attributes to each unique element child of an element

Tags: php, xml, data-structures, simplexml, domdocument

I have been troubleshooting this for a while, and I am kind of new to programming.  Even when I find an error, it's very difficult to figure out how to correct it.  Right now, I am trying to figure out how I have used xpath wrong because someone told me that I am using xpath wrong.  I hope someone can give me a jump start by telling me what I am doing wrong, specifically with iterating, if I am doing anything wrong.  This is my last night to work on this project, and I really want to finish it if I can.  So, I could really use help.  Here is the code I am using, with comments:

```php
$xml = @simplexml_load_file("original.xml"); //Loading the original file, dubbed original.xml.
$array_key_target_parent = count($xml->xpath('/doc/*'); //Puts all of the children of <doc> into an _iterable_ array.
$key_targets = foreach($array_key_target_parent;){
  foreach($array_key_target_parent as $single_target){ // I tried foreach($array_key_target_parent[$i]).  It doesn't work, so don't even go there.
    $current_target = current($single_target);
    count($xml->xpath('/doc/$current_target/*');
  }
} */ ////Puts the targets for keying into iterable arrays.  =>1 makes the array start from 1, so the id's will be right.


/* At this point, we have multiple elements that we want to key, each having a unique name.  There's <element_type1a> and <element_type1b>, etc.  We want each one to have its own id set.  So, we have to embed iteration within iteration. */
foreach($key_target){ //This will ensure that every unique element that we want to key gets its key set.
  {
  $id = current($key_target=>1); //This allows us to reset the id to 1 (=>1), each time the key algorithm starts for a new element.
  foreach($key_target as $id){ //I tried for($i=0, $key_target[$i]; $i>$key_target; $i++), and it didn't work, so don't even go there.
    addAttribute('id', '$id');
  }
}  //Adds an 'id' attribute and a unique number to each target.

$xml->asXML("new.xml"); //saves the output as a new xml document, new.xml
```

I also have a generic XML file:

```
<doc>
    <info_type1>
        <element_type1a>not_unique_data</element_type1a>
        <element_type1b>unique_data</element_type1b>
        <element_type2a>not_unique_data</element_type2a>
        <element_type2b>not_unique_data</element_type2b>
        <element_type2c lang="fr">not_unique_data</element_type2c>
        <!-- ... --->
        <element_typeNxM>unique_data</element_typeNxM>
    </info_type1>
    <info_type2>
        <element_type1a>repeat_data(info_type1_element1a)</element_type1a>
        <element_type2a>not_unique_data</element_type2a>
    </info_type2>
    <!-- ... --->
    <info_typeN>
        <descendants></descendants>
    </info_typeN>
</doc>
```

Desired output:

```
<datatables>
    <table id="element_type1">
        <element_type1a id="1">unique_data</element_type1a>
        <element_type1b id="2">unique_data</element_type1b>
        <!-- ... --->
        <element_type1N id="M">unique_data</element_type1N>
    </table>
    <table id="element_type2">
        <element_type2a id="1">unique_data</element_type2a>
        <element_type2b id="2">unique_data</element_type2b>
        <!-- ... --->
        <element_type2N id="M">unique_data</element_type2N>
    </table>
    <table id="element_type2_fr">
        <element_type2a lang="fr" id="1">unique_data</element_type2a>
        <element_type2b lang="fr" id="2">unique_data</element_type2>
        <!-- ... (there are five languages) --->
        <element_type2N lang="fr" id="M">unique_data</element_type2N>
    </table>
    <!-- ... --->
    <table id="element_typeN">
        <descendants></descendants>
    </table>
</datatables>
```

and

```
<intermediary_tables>
    <table id="intermediary_table_type1xtype2">
        <element id="1">
            <type1ID>1</type1ID>
            <type2ID>1</type2ID>
        </element>
        <element id="2">
            <type1ID>1</type1ID>
            <type2ID>2</type2ID>
        </element>
        <element id="3">
            <type1ID>2</type1ID>
            <type2ID>1</type2ID>
        </element>
        <element id="4">
            <type1ID>2</type1ID>
            <type2ID>2</type2ID>
        </element>
        <!-- ... --->
        <element id="N">
            <type1ID>M</type1ID>
            <type2ID>Z</type2ID>
        </element_type2N>
    </table>

    <table id="intermediary_table_typeMxtypeN">
        <descendants></descendants>
    </table>
</intermediary_tables>
```

I have also seen many very similar questions asked, and I have some resources that I gathered from them and read:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlphp1/index.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php
- http://www.learn-xslt-tutorial.com/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103.aspx
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

These are the most useful links:

- http://www.capcourse.com/Library/NormalizingXML/Part1.html
- http://forums.tizag.com/showthread.php?t=17821

And I found that none of the applications of the questions were able to produce the result I am trying to achieve.  The exception, though, is the capcourse.com link.  It's geared towards a graduated CS audience, and it seems like they're doing the same thing, except the ID's they are using aren't autoincrementing.  The algorithm they use is extremely complex, and they haven't commented their code at all.  They're using a namespace within their namespace for some reason, and even though it's the closest I can find, I can't reproduce it in the slightest.

---

**Update**

Real-world extract from an XML document that I would like to parse to change the data structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog [
<!ELEMENT catalog (entry*)>
<!ELEMENT entry (ent_seq, country*, arist+, info?, title+)><!-- Entries consist of the name of the album, artist, and more information about the CD.  Each entry must contain an artist and an album title. -->
<!ELEMENT ent_seq (#PCDATA)><!-- A unique numeric sequence, showing the entry number -->
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)><!-- The title of the album/the album name. -->
<!ELEMENT artist (band+, name, nickname*)><!-- The name of the band, and if there was a famous artist, his name and nickname.  Must contain a band element. -->
<!ELEMENT band (#PCDATA)><!-- The name of the band. -->
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)><!-- The name of any famous artist in the band. -->
<!ELEMENT nickname (#PCDATA)><!-- The nickname of the popular artist that precedes the nickname element, from the band. -->
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)><!-- Specifies countries where the album was released -->
<!ELEMENT company (name, country)><!-- Company/producer info.  The company's name is in the name element, and the country where the company originated is in the country element. -->
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)><!-- The name of the producer -->
<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)><!-- The country where the company does its primary business -->
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)><!-- The year of the album's release -->
<!ELEMENT info (link*, bibl*)><!-- Additional info, including links and bibliography information -->
<!ELEMENT link (#PCDATA)><!-- Links where people can read more about the album -->
<!ELEMENT bibl (#PCDATA)><!-- Bibliography text about the artist -->
]>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <ent_seq>1</ent_seq>
    <title>For Your Love</title>
    <artist>
      <name>The Yardbirds</name>
      <name>Eric Clapton</name>
      <nickname>Slowhand</nickname>
    </artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>
      <name>Sweet Music</name>
      <country>USA</country>
    </company>
    <year>1965</year>
    <info>
      <link>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Your_Love</link>
    </info>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <ent_seq>2</ent_seq>
    <title>Splish Splash</title>
    <artist>
      <name>Roberto Carlos</name>
      <nickname>The King</nickname>
    </artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <country>Brazil</country>
    <country>Italy</country>
    <company>
      <name>Sweet Music</name>
    <country>Brazil</country>
    </company>
    <year>1965</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <ent_seq>3</ent_seq>
    <title>How Great Thuo Art</title>
    <artist>
      <name>Elvis Presley</name>
      <nickname>The King</nickname>
      <nickname>The King of Rock 'n Roll</nickname>
    </artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <country>Canada</country>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>
      <name>Felton Jarvis</name>
      <country>USA</country>
    </company>
    <year>1965</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <ent_seq>4</ent_seq>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>
      <band>Will Smith</band>
      <name>Will Smith</name>
    </artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <ent_seq>5</ent_seq>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>
      <band>Bob Dylan and Boby Rockhammer</band>
      <name>Bob Dylan</name>
      <name>Boby Rockhammer</name>
    </artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <country>India</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>  <!-- Update part 1: New Entry -->
    <ent_seq>6</ent_seq>
    <title>Merry Christmas</title>
    <title>White Christmas</title>
    <artist>
      <name>Bing Crosby</name>
    <artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>MCA Records</company>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd> <!-- End update part 1-->
</catalog>
```

Real-world example of desired output sample:

```
<datatable>
  <table id="album title">
    <title id="1">For your Love</title>
    <title id="2">Splish Splash</title>
    <title id="3">How Great Thuo Art</title>
    <title id="4">Big Willie style</title>
    <title id="5">Empire Burlesque</title>
    <title id="6">Merry Christmas</title> <!-- Update part 2: New output -->
    <title id="7">White Christmas</title> <!-- Update part 2: New output -->
  </table>
  <table id="Band Name">
    <artist id="1">The Yardbirds</artist>
    <artist id="2">Roberto Carlos</artist>
    <artist id="3">Elvis Presley</artist>
    <artist id="4">Will Smith</artist>
    <artist id="5">Bob Dylan and Boby Rockhammer</artist>
    <artist id="6"> <!-- Update part 2: New output -->
  </table>
  <table id="artist name">
    <artist id="1">Eric Clapton</artist>
    <artist id="2">Roberto Carlos</artist>
    <artist id="3">Elvis Presley</artist>
    <artist id="4">Will Smith</artist>
    <artist id="5">Bob Dylan</artist>
    <artist id="6">Boby Rockhammer</artist>
    <artist id="7">Bing Crosby</artist> <!-- Update part 2: New output -->
  </table>
  <table id="nickname">
    <nickname id="1">Slowhand</nickname>
    <nickname id="2">The King</nickname>
    <nickname id="3">The King of Rock 'n Roll</nickname>
  </table>
</datatable>
```

and

```
<intermediarytable>
  <table id="artist by band name">
    <entry id="1">
      <band_id>1</band_id>
      <artist_id>1</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2">
      <band_id>2</band_id>
      <artist_id>2</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="3">
      <band_id>3</band_id>
      <artist_id>3</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="4">
      <band_id>4</band_id>
      <artist_id>4</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="5">
      <band_id>5</band_id>
      <artist_id>5</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="6">
      <band_id>5</band_id>
      <artist_id>6</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="7">
      <band_id>6</band_id>
      <artist_id>7</artist_id>
    </entry>
  </table>
  <table id="artist by nickname">
    <entry id="1">
      <artist_id>1</artist_id>
      <nickname_id>1</artist_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="2">
      <artist_id>2</artist_id>
      <nickname_id>2</nickname_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="3">
      <artist_id>2</artist_id>
      <nickname_id>3</nickname_id>
    </entry>
    <entry id="4">
      <artist_id>3</artist_id>
      <nickname_id>3</nickname_id>
    </entry>
  </table>
</intermediarytable>
```

**--UPDATE-- There's an issue in which two elements share the same entry ID**

In another XML doc I have,

```
<entry id="1">
  <word>blue</word>
  <word>beryl</word>
  <word lang="SP">azul</word>
</entry>
```

and I want the output to be

Data Tables:

```
<table id="en">
  <word lang="en" id="0">blue</word>
  <word lang="en" id="1">beryl</word>
</table>
<table id="sp">
  <word lang="sp" id="0">azul</word>
</table>
```

Intermediary Table:

```
<table id="translation id">
  <en_sp id="0"> <!-- en_sp means English-to-Spanish -->
    <en>0</en>
    <sp>0</sp>
  </en_sp>
  <en_sp>
    <en>1</en>
    <sp>0</sp>
  </en_sp>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow your PHP code is all wrong. Almost every single line makes no sense. What are you trying to do - translate an XSLT stylesheet into PHP?

Comment: If I do it in XSLT, I have to call a custom XSD namespace in the XSLT document that calls an XSD namespace, in order to nest the iterations properly.  XSLT is more complicated.  So, if I had to translate, I would probably be starting with the easier language.  I'm thinking about starting over with domdocument, but it would only mean changing 3 lines in the php.  Can you please tell me what's wrong with the php?  I want to edit it.

Comment: For example, I wrote $id = current($keytarget=>1);, and I was wondering if I had to write the =>1 when I defined $keytarget, right after the xpath statement?

Comment: Maybe we start this from the other end. Your goal is to change the input XML. Please provide a desired output XML for your test case and we can see how it's easiest to get there.

Comment: Okay, but by providing the output I'm scaring everyone else away.  @Tomalak The output is beastly.

Comment: After formatting everything in XML in this way, I want to move the data to a MySQL database.

Comment: This looks like a job for XSLT, not for PHP. If you don't mind I'd prefer creating an XSLT solution. But to do this I need a real-world sample, not a made-up one. Can you change your samples to a minimum snippet of data that you *actually* have?

Comment: @Tomalak, I'll pull data out of one of the XML files I am trying to convert.  The made-up sample uses real xml, but I guess it would be nice to see some actual xml converted.

Comment: I would try to just key each element individually, but then how would I do the intermediary tables?

Comment: The real world example you've provided (this time ;-)) seems to indicate that you're trying to "relationalize" the xml document. Though I also opted for xsl in your previous question on the subject now I'm not so sure anymore (though it's still possible). What's the source of the input document, i.e. from where do you get it and do you have influenece on how and where it's created? And why do you want the output document in this format and what are you going to do with the output document? (don't take it the wrong way, it just seems to me atm you're a bit out of your league with the problem)

Comment: @VolkerK Those are good questions. I'm sure I can solve this via XSLT but I'm somehow not sure if it would do any good, or if it would rather just add complexity to the problem.

Comment: @VolkerK, The goal is to put the data into a MySQL database for easier manipulation.  Some of the data changes a lot, and a lot of data is still being added.  The CD catalog is one example, but I'm also trying to alter a catalog of books, and I have a dictionary catalog that is the biggest priority, in my opinion, because it's undergoing the most changes.  They're all structured in the same way.  I don't have a lot of influence over how they are created, but I'm trying to plug them into an application for alteration.  I'm more familiar with MySQL+php than I am with XML, also...

Comment: ...so, it would make the development of the application a lot easier.  Right now, the CD catalog is only consisting of about 500 entries, and I could probably do everything by hand.  The books catalog has over 2000 entries, and the dictionary has over 5000-9000 entries per XML file (there are three of them), which were made to this standard.  The docs are now abandonware for a project, but I think that they could be very useful.  I was given permission to use them, and I would really like to put them into a normalized database.

Comment: I know it seems like the book data and the CD data wouldn't change a lot, but I think that things like nickname and biography will change a lot.  Also, I want to add additional tables.

Comment: More justification for the solution is that I've found a lot of people trying to do the same thing, and they don't have a solution.  If I could figure it out, I would be able to help a lot of people to do the same thing.  It would move many programming projects forward.  I think being able to answer this question would be so useful for so many people, so I have a lot of ambition for the result.  By getting over this roadblock in multiple projects, there's no telling what kind of new technology could come alongside.

Comment: How can I add a bounty to this question?  Anyone?

Comment: I want to do the same thing, and I have no idea.  The PHP manual for SimpleXML and DomDocument is really junky.  Here's a link that might help you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlphp1/index.html.  They also have a part 2 and part 3.  It's like a 15-minute guide to domdocument.  I'm probably less skilled than you at PHP because your code looks fine to me.  I hope this pushes you along!

Comment: @VolkerK, I added a 50-point bounty.  I want to save some of my points to bounty other questions if needs be, but I am even willing to go 100 points. x//  You can do it! *ra cha cha*  You can do it! :D :D :D

Comment: @Fohsap I wouldn't transform the xml document this way but transfer the data "directly" to the relational database if that's the ultimate goal anyway. I.e. using the database itself as the lookup instead of having some intermediate data structure(s).

Comment: But during the transfer, you have to indicate up the relationship, so that the database can recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***--UPDATES***

Assuming an xml like this:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <entry id="1">
      <word>blue</word>
      <word>beryl</word>
      <word lang="SP">azul</word>
    </entry>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <entry id="2">
  ...
```

try this:

```
$super = array();
$url = "original.xml";
if ($xml = @simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)) {
  foreach($xml->cd as $cd) {
     foreach ($cd->entry as $entry) {
      $id = (string)$entry['id'];
        foreach($entry->word as $word) {
            $lang = isset($word['lang']) ? (string)$word['lang'] : 'EN';
            $super[$id][$lang][] = (string)$word;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

display using:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($super);
print "</pre>";
```

**note:** this is another approach, substantially what you need to understand when working with xml object and more in general with arrays is that you can store data by creating a structured hierarchy based on parent -> child; in this case i'm have created an array like this `$super[$id][$lang][] = (string)$word;` where `$id` is parent of `$lang` that is parent of `$word` that is respectively child of both; this will produce an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [EN] => Array
                (
                    [0] => blue
                    [1] => beryl
                )

            [SP] => Array
                (
                    [0] => azul
                )

        )
      ...
```

other things to consider are,

1. how to get the properties of matched tags like `id` or `lang`, in my example i have used `$entry['id']` but `$cd->entry['id']` is also valid.
2. how to convert an xml-dom-object into a valid string, so that you can reuse it as array index or value like `(string)$word`

---

from what i can see from your examples:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <ent_seq>1</ent_seq>
    <title>For Your Love</title>
    <artist>
    ...
```

try this

```
$super = array();
$url = "original.xml";
if ($xml = @simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)) {
  $xml_array = @json_decode(@json_encode($xml), 1);
  foreach ($xml_array['cd'] as $val) {
  $key = $val['ent_seq'];
    if (is_array($val)) {
      foreach ($val as $k1 => $v1) {
        if (is_array($v1)) {
          switch ($k1) {
            case 'artist':
              foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
                if (is_array($v2)) {
                  foreach ($v2 as $v3) {
                    $super[$k2][$key] = $v3;
                  }
                }
                else {
                  $super[$k2][$key] = $v2;
                }
              }
              break;
          }
        }
        else {
          switch ($k1) {
            case 'title':
              $super[$k1][$key] = $v1;
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

display the results iterating through the array like this:

```
foreach( $super as $key => $val) {
  echo "<table id='{$key}'>\n";
   foreach($val as $key2 => $val2) {
    echo "<$key id='$key2'> " . $val2." </$key>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";                

}
```

in order to have a better view of the array struct you can print it like this:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($super);
print "</pre>";
```

this will display an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [1] => For Your Love
            [2] => Splish Splash
            [3] => How Great Thuo Art
            [4] => Big Willie style
            [5] => Empire Burlesque
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [1] => Eric Clapton
            [2] => Roberto Carlos
            [3] => Elvis Presley
            [4] => Will Smith
            [5] => Boby Rockhammer
        )

    [nickname] => Array
        (
            [1] => Slowhand
            [2] => The King
            [3] => The King of Rock 'n Roll
        )

    [band] => Array
        (
            [4] => Will Smith
            [5] => Bob Dylan and Boby Rockhammer
        )

)
```

**note:** as you can see i made use of `switch`-case, cause your xml-tags are not always the same consistence and they have similar-name in some circumstances like `<company><name>` and `<artist><name>`; you can create your own cases.

however as is now, it work well with the fields you want to grab as in da example.

Comment: This is very good.  There is only one issue, which is using JSON to get the Key because there are chronological titles whose names were changed.  Like "White Christmas" was always "Merry Christmas" until the CD version came out, and we've listed <cd> <ent_seq><title>original</title><title>current<title> </cd>.  I guess I could just use $key[1] and $key[0]?  May I also ask what you think the best solution is?  I'm sorry I didn't ask about it.

Comment: i have used json to convert the xml-object to an array for easy access; i'm not sure what you are talking about in the comment, pls post this other xml schema, so i can be more precise.

Comment: I added it.  I can see how you've made things FAR more simple for me.  Anyway, to make things easier to see, I will also add info from another XML document, right now.

Comment: Also, regardless of whether or not you are able to find time to answer the follow-up question, which I would really appreciate, I definitely feel that you have routed the question with your answer.  I'm very happy with the result, and I really want to say thank you.

Comment: Wow, that's so wordy: "$super[$id][$lang][] = (string)$word; where $id is parent of $lang that is parent of $word that is respectively child of both..."  That's wild.  Thanks, for the info.  We really have to wiki this.  It's crazy good.

Comment: But then, how would you get the intermediary table, which shows the relationship between the <word lang="en"> table and the <word lang="sp"> table (i.e., <translation><en>0</en><sp>0</sp></translation>, or <name_nickname_lookup><name>3</name><nickname>3</nickname></name_nickname_lookup>?  Can you use the existing variables, somehow, or would it be necessary to repeat the process somehow?

Comment: you should do me a favor: remove all the code from your post and put just the real, full example of your xml file, so i can make a full-working demo for you. let me know.

Comment: The full example is about 54 megabytes.  Is there any way I could send you a file or catch you in chat, or just send you a longer example?  Everything seems to work on the full file, but there's no intermediary table.  The data table is like english: blue, beryl, water; spanish; azul, agua.  The intermediary would be like: blueXazul, berylXazul, waterXagua.

Comment: ok, now i'm little busy, as soon as i have a few minutes, i will post the example loop to make the intermediate struct! ;-)

Comment: Ａｗｅｓｅｏｍｅ！ I'll totally tack on another bounty. :D

Comment: @千里ちゃん: If you add `foreach($xml_array['cd']){$myObject = new Super();}` and create an object called `$myObject` that matches, you can do a little editing and create: for `$n` CD's in your catalog, `$n = count($xml_array['cd']`.  I don't know how to get null values, but this will give you an implicit primary key.  You can iterate through the objects, and you can instruct your port-to-db script to put `null` where no value is present.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work, though.  I tried copying it and pasting it as it is.  It returns `Array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you are trying to take an input XML document, convert it to another (differently formatted) xml document using XSL/T, and then take the resulting XML and store it in your MySQL database?

I'm new to stack overflow, so I'm not sure how add a comment to the original post.

Comment: You cannot comment until you have gathered a minimal amount of reputation points. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/privileges to see what you can to at which stage.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I checked the privileges after I had posted. :)

Comment: The points required for basic interaction with the site (up- and down-voting, commenting)  are easy to get. 50 points is a matter of a few hours at max.

Comment: I had the same problem, Tomalak, and I was very unsure as to why I couldn't comment on any posts but the ones I asked or answered. :)

Comment: I'll work on the output, Tomalak.  I've put the input in the post in my update.

Comment: In the most recent update, I also added a real-world 'desired output' codeblock.

Comment: Anyway, yes.  That is the goal.

Comment: Well, looking at the desired output compared to the input, I can already see a problem using XSL.  What you're are trying to do can only be done where a 1 to 1 relationship of attributes exists for each cd "node".  So, the first question is...how do you plan to handle multiple nodes of the same type, such as Nickname or Country.

Comment: For example, Elvis has two nickname nodes, "The King" and "The King of Rock 'n Roll". How do you plan to associate both of those nickname nodes with "Elvis" - Your output document does not appear to have any method or key constraint that ties one to the other, since the ID fields do not match up.

Comment: I think that there could be two separate arrays created from the elements.  One array would contain all of the elements that should not contain duplicates, and the other array should contain all of the elements that should allow duplicates.  Then, use a different but very similar algorithm to process the two arrays.  There would have to be a comparison made for the elements that shouldn't allow duplicates.  That shouldn't be hard in PHP, but I have never used XSL.  I did, however, find an article about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669813/how-do-i-prevent-duplicates-in-xsl.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid Good comment.  Glad you noticed that, so if an answerer ever answers this question, I hope they include a solution for that issue.  We should definitely make the answer into a community wiki. :D

Comment: @Fohsap, I would do something like that by adding `foreach (//element as $element){$i=0; $i++; $check = array_slice($element, 0, $i); if ($element(current) == $check){where($element(current)==$check){$text=$xml->xpath(//$element(current)(text)));}$copyval=count($text);for($xml->$copyval[0]){copy-of-attribute($xml->intermediarytable)); deleteElement($xml->$copyval[1]);}}}....`  Yeah it's complicated, and I'm pretty tired to be doing this without an interpreter.  You get the idea.  Let me come back to it.

Comment: You can actually use @seen... if @seen==true, then you can re-search the array for the 1st and 2nd entry that matches and have its key in the array returned.  Take that return value and add it in the intermediary table.  Then, delete the 2nd match.

Comment: @Fohsap So can you bounty it yet? hehe

Comment: Well, I'm pretty certain I can create a solution to provide a properly constructed output XML doc using XSL/T -- but I still get hung up on the fact that XML + XSL is a set based transaction - I can transform the output just about any way possible, but it seems to me that you would still have to rely on a stored proc in your MySQL to handle dividing each entity within the incoming XML into the various "relational" aspects using key constraints.  XSL depends on everything "relational" being node or set based, and you break that model with the 1 to multiple example I asked about above.